# Strategies for dealing with inflexible 3rd party libraries

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, properties-file, legacy-code

I need help controlling the behavior of a couple of 3rd party libraries I am required to use in my application:

- *DBLib*, which is required for database access
- *PropsLib*, which is required by *DBLib* for configuration

*DBLib* makes a lot of static-method calls to *PropsLib* to acquire configuration settings. For example: `String dbHost = PropsLib.getString("dbHost")`. *PropsLib* uses non-standard `.properties` files that is reads from the filesystem. (non-standard meaning they have a quirky placeholder syntax that doesn't match any of our other `.properties` files) Also, the method for externalizing (overriding) those files per-environment is strange and clunky.

Are there any design strategies I could use that would allow me to use my existing Spring-based configuration mechanisms here? Or is my only option to write my own implementation of the *PropsLib* library?

Comment: This sounds too broad especially without having *PropsLib* source. Nevertheless according to your description the *PropsLib* should not be something very sophisticated, so rewriting it sounds a reasonable option.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't include any source. The _PropsLib_ library is proprietary so I can't. The general functionality of the library is: read .properties from filesystem, parse, return string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `PropsLib` is as short and easy as you described, I would recommend you to reimplement it in your own code to cheat `DBLib` and retrieve your spring-based configuration, instead using the properties file you *hate* :)

Of course, if `PropsLib` is in a `.jar` you would need to remove it from that archive before. You could also include your own version inside the `.jar` but this is not mandatory.